# How to override application.properties by command line parameter to specify datasource properties

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, connection-pooling

I am using spring boot 2.0.5. I am building an application with embedded tomcat. I have a requirement where the data-source URL needs to be specified as a command line parameter to the jar when starting the application. As the application is meant to run in the desktop of various customers and there can be few databases out of which the application instance has to use one.

I am facing a problem where spring boot is always picking values from application.properties and not overriding its values by what I specify in the command line.

How do I make spring override data source properties by the ones specified in the command line?

I also tried passing commandline parameter

```
java -jar my_app.jar --server.port=8080 --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssm-entp
```

below is my data-source XML config.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:application.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />




    <!-- <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="5" /> -->
</bean>
```

Comment: I can’t tell if it’s causing your problem (you haven’t provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve)), but configuring your own `DataSource` and using XML to do so is quite unusual in Spring Boot. Why not use the auto-configured `DataSource` and Java-based configuration where needed instead?